# Multi size .ico generator

Tags: webapp-rec

I need to generate a multi size ICO file for a desktop software icon. It needs to contain the following sizes:

```
16x16 (32-bit)
32x32 (32-bit)
48x48 (32-bit)
96x96 (32-bit)
128x128 (32-bit)
256x256 (32-bit)
```

Is there a web app that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ConvertICO.org](http://convertico.org/) can do it. Select the input file, then select the output icon type with **Custom Dimensions (Multi-size in one icon)** setting, and finally click Convert button. Now you can download your multi-size icon file.

[image: sshot]